# Python: sort by date and time?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of objects that each contain a datetime.date() and a datetime.time() element. I know how to sort the array based on a single element using insertion sort, or any other sorting algorithm. However, how would I sort this list in chronological order using date AND time?

Comment: If you're not trying to practice your sorting algorithms, you should use the built-in `sorted()`.

Comment: A date/time-of-day is itself a single value representing a single instance in Time when combined (Why would there be a *date* and a *time* separate? Do you mean, eg., there is a Created Time and a Modified Time? If not, the key function should just return the Time.) In any case, to sort by two values (such as a Name and a Time), simply return a Tuple of [Name, Time] from the key function. See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tuple of `(my_date, my_time)` as the "single element" you're sorting on. You could build a `datetime.datetime` object from the two, but that seems unnecessary just to sort them.

This applies in general to any situation where you want a lexicographical comparison between multiple quantities. "Lexicographical" meaning, most-significant first with less-significant quantities as tie-breakers, which is exactly what the standard comparisons do for `tuple`.